Could Jordan have saved his company and avoided arrest if he hadn’t made that mistake?
Jordan goes to work wearing a wire, but manages to slip Donnie a note warning him.
However, Jordan makes a foolish mistake by not discarding the slip, leading the FBI
to find out. This results in Jordan’s arrest and the raid and shutdown of Stratton
Oakmont:

Could Jordan have saved his company and avoided arrest if he hadn’t made that mistake?

We can't really speculate on what would have happened in the fictional Wolf of Wall Street film had he been more cooperative. We can, however, look at the source novel on which the film was based.
In reality, Jordan had already been arrested and was in the processes of being charged with various crimes when he agreed to wear a wire.

Meanwhile, on the legal front, things were going even worse. It was on my fourth day out of jail when the U.S. attorney called my lawyer and told him that unless I pleaded guilty and became a government witness he was going to indict the Duchess too. And while he didn’t get specific on the charges, my best guess was that she was going to be indicted for conspiracy to spend obscene amounts of money. What else was she guilty of, after all?
Either way, the world was upside down. How could I, the one at the very top of the food chain, rat out those beneath me? Did giving up a multitude of smaller fish offset the fact that I was the biggest fish in town? Was it a matter of simple mathematics: that fifty guppies added up to a single whale?
Cooperating meant that I would have to wear a wire; that I would have to testify at trials and take the witness stand against my friends.

At the point at which he agreed to act as a government witness his company was already doomed and Jordan was already expected (by his own lawyer) to be jailed for up to a decade.
